# How to optimize multivariate functions in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scipy-optimize

I have this dataframe:

[image]

where:

```
x: independent variable
y: independent variable
z: dependent variable
```

How do I find in Python the optimal "a" and "b" parameters , so that I optimize this function:

```
z = a*sin(x) + b*sin(y)
```

I know that the optimal solution is:

```
a = 0
b = 1
```

But what Python code should I use? I guess I should use scipy optimize, but I am only able to use it with one independent variable.

Comment: Could you share your dataframe? (e.g. by providing the output of `df.to_records()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider `sklearn`:

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`, first thing you might want to do is create a variable `X` containing the sin-transform of `x,y`, e.g.

```
from math import sin


X = [[sin(x), sin(y)] for x, y in zip(df.x, df.y)]
```

and then a variable `Z` which is `df.z`.

Finally, you can just do a linear regression fit using`sklearn`, e.g.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, Z)
```

Comment: aahh that's the bit I was missing ! thanks !